# Save matplotlib file to a directory

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the simple code which generates and saves a plot image in the same directory as of the  code. Now, is there a way through which I can save it in directory of choice?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(100))

fig.savefig('graph.png')
```

Answer (score 65):

If the directory you wish to save to is a sub-directory of your working directory, simply specify the relative path before your file name:

```
    fig.savefig('Sub Directory/graph.png')
```

If you wish to use an absolute path, import the [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module:

```
    import os
    my_path = os.path.abspath(__file__) # Figures out the absolute path for you in case your working directory moves around.
    ...
    fig.savefig(my_path + '/Sub Directory/graph.png')
```

If you don't want to worry about the leading slash in front of the sub-directory name, you can join paths intelligently as follows:

```
    import os
    my_path = os.path.abspath(__file__) # Figures out the absolute path for you in case your working directory moves around.
    my_file = 'graph.png'
    ...
    fig.savefig(os.path.join(my_path, my_file))
```

Comment: The path for the directory should be `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Answer (score 22):

Here's the piece of code that saves plot to the selected directory. If the directory does not exist, it is created.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
results_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'Results/')
sample_file_name = "sample"

if not os.path.isdir(results_dir):
    os.makedirs(results_dir)

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.savefig(results_dir + sample_file_name)
```

Answer (score 19):

According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) `savefig` accepts a file path, so all you need is to specify a full (or relative) path instead of a file name.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the answers already given, if you want to create a new directory, you could use this function:

```
def mkdir_p(mypath):
    '''Creates a directory. equivalent to using mkdir -p on the command line'''

    from errno import EEXIST
    from os import makedirs,path

    try:
        makedirs(mypath)
    except OSError as exc: # Python >2.5
        if exc.errno == EEXIST and path.isdir(mypath):
            pass
        else: raise
```

and then:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(100))

# Create new directory
output_dir = "some/new/directory"
mkdir_p(output_dir)

fig.savefig('{}/graph.png'.format(output_dir))
```

Answer (score 11):

The **simplest way** to do this is as follows:

---

```
save_results_to = '/Users/S/Desktop/Results/'
plt.savefig(save_results_to + 'image.png', dpi = 300)
```

---

The image is going to be saved in the `save_results_to` directory with name `image.png`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example for saving to a directory(external usb drive) using Python version 2.7.10 with Sublime Text 2 editor:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint = True)
C, S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

plt.plot(X, C, color = "blue", linewidth = 1.0, linestyle = "-")
plt.plot(X, S, color = "red", linewidth = 1.0, linestyle = "-")

plt.savefig("/Volumes/seagate/temp_swap/sin_cos_2.png", dpi = 72)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

```
name ='mypic'
plt.savefig('path_to_file/{}'.format(name))
```

If you want to save in same folder where your code lies,ignore the path_to_file and just format with name.
If you have folder name *'Images'* in the just one level outside of your python script, you can use,

```
name ='mypic'
plt.savefig('Images/{}'.format(name))
```

The default file type in saving is *'.png'* file format. 
If you want to save in loop, then you can use the unique name for each file such as counter of the for loop. If i is the counter,

```
plt.savefig('Images/{}'.format(i))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way :

```
plt.savefig( r'root path' +  str(variable)  + '.pdf' )
```

In this example I also created a file format and made a variable as string.

'r' stands for root.

for example :

```
plt.savefig( r'D:\a\b\c' +  str(v)  + '.pdf' )
```

ENJOY !!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the file path (directory) before the name of the image. Example:

```
fig.savefig('/home/user/Documents/graph.png')
```

Other example:

```
fig.savefig('/home/user/Downloads/MyImage.png')
```