# How to specify a directory in which to save an image using plotly py.image.save_as

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I would like to save the plot images I generate into a specific directory, but `save_as` only has a `filename` argument.
I'm using the following code to save the plots

`py.image.save_as(fig,filename='T_avg_'+lst_QoST_prop[i]+'.pdf')`

Is there a way to specify a directory?

Comment: And? What is your question?

Comment: Have you tried using a path where the `filename` argument is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save matplotlib file to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373610/save-matplotlib-file-to-a-directory)

Comment: @running.t  I would like to save the output which is a PDF file into a specific directory.

Comment: @MoxieBall Yes, I have, it didn't work, it renames the output file like what's given in the argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to save your file in a specific file path you need to use `filename` parameter.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
help(py.image)
```

> ```
>  |  Helper functions wrapped around plotly's static image generation api.
>  |
>  |  Class methods defined here:
>  |  save_as(figure_or_data, filename, format=None, width=None, height=None, scale=None) from builtins.type
>  |      Save a image of the plot described by `figure_or_data` locally as
>  |      `filename`.
>  |
>  |      Valid image formats are 'png', 'svg', 'jpeg', and 'pdf'.
>  |      The format is taken as the extension of the filename or as the
>  |      supplied format.
>  |
>  |      positional arguments:
>  |      - figure_or_data: The figure dict-like or data list-like object that
>  |                        describes a plotly figure.
>  |                        Same argument used in `py.plot`, `py.iplot`,
>  |                        see https://plot.ly/python for examples
>  |      - filename: The filepath to save the image to
>  |      - format: 'png', 'svg', 'jpeg', 'pdf'
>  |      - width: output width
>  |      - height: output height
>  |      - scale: Increase the resolution of the image by `scale` amount
>  |             Only valid for PNG and JPEG images.
> ```

### ***Using filename with path (offline):***

> *However, this results in a HTML file that's opened in a new tab of the*
>   *browser. The image is saved to the 'Downloads' folder, and it's not*
>   *possible to specify the path at which the image should be saved.*

```
from plotly.offline import py
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter

plot([Scatter(x=[14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 89],
              y=[30, 15, 18, 30, 24, 27, 50])], filename='2/billympoufo.html')
```

So you'll have the html file in the specified folder (image in download folder) in order to bypass browser behavior you can: 
***(1)*** import `copyfile` from `shutil` and move the image.

```
import os
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import time
from shutil import copyfile

img_name = 'billympoufo'
dload = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
save_dir = '/tmp'

data = [go.Scatter(x=[14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84, 89, 1], y=[30, 15, 18, 30, 24, 27, 50, 36, 39, 42, 50, 48, 51, 54])]

plotly.offline.plot(data, image_filename=img_name, image='svg')

### might need to wait for plot to download before copying
time.sleep(1)

copyfile('{}/{}.svg'.format(dload, img_name),
     '{}/{}.svg'.format(save_dir, img_name))
```

> for more offline options: ***(2)*** check chromium or ***(3)*** [Firefox download
>   behavior](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file).
>  By using the parameter `auto_open=False` it
>   should save the image in the folder without opening a tab in your
>   browser but this was an an issue, 
> check here: [Directly save image
>   (without opening in browser) #880](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/880) 
> and plotly didn't plan to
>   add this feature at that time.
>   Also you can ***(4)*** use selenium to screenshot the page

### In Jupiter, for offline saving you can do the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import time    
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display 

### from bokeh/io, slightly modified to avoid their import_required util
### didn't ultimately use, but leaving in case I figure out how to stick wtih phentomjs
### - https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/io/export.py
def create_default_webdriver():
    '''Return phantomjs enabled webdriver'''
    phantomjs_path = detect_phantomjs()
    return webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path, service_log_path=devnull)    

### based on last SO answer above
### - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615811/how-to-download-a-file-with-python-selenium-and-phantomjs
def create_chromedriver_webdriver(dload_path):
    display = Display(visible=0)
    display.start()
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": dload_path}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver, display
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'fruits': ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries'],
     'counts': [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6] })    
data = [go.Bar(x=df['fruits'],y=df['counts'])]    
dload = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
html_file = 'plotly-fruit-plot.html'
fname = 'plotly-fruit-plot'

### original code contained height/width for the display and chromium webdriver
### I found they didn't matter; specifying the image size to generate will 
### produce a plot of that size no matter the webdriver
plotly.offline.plot(data, filename=html_file, auto_open=False,
                    image_width=1280, image_height=800,image_filename=fname, image='png')

### create webdrive, open file, maximize, and sleep
driver, display = create_chromedriver_webdriver(dload)    
driver.get('file:///{}'.format(os.path.abspath(html_file)))

# make sure we give the file time to download
time.sleep(1)

### was in the SO post and could be a more robust way to wait vs. just sleeping 1sec
# while not(glob.glob(os.path.join(dl_location, filename))):
#     time.sleep(1)    
driver.close()
display.stop()    
image = Image.open('{}.png'.format(os.path.join(dload, fname)))
image
```

(source: [jupiter](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/jwhendy/8542f9f330796814d98cf94a3c0caf6d))

---

### ***or online folder:***

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
# sign in
data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=[14, 19, 24, 29, 5, 10, 22],
        y=[15, 18, 30, 24, 27, 30, 40]
    )
]

plot_out = py.plot(data, filename='all_my_graphs/my_new_plot')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to save an image in a folder with python. That question already has an answer if you search.

The function I use is

> savefig()

Example :

```
plot = dtf.plot() 

fig = plot.get_figure() 

fig.savefig("output.png") or fig.savefig("output.pdf") ...
```

Also, you will have to import matplotlib library:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: it didn't work. Note, that I'm not using matplotlib for generating the graph, I would like to keep using plotly

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way i found, any doubts, just follow the documentation https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/

Install before>> pip install -U kaleido

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import os

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=["A"],
                     y=[25],
                     marker_color='rgb(55, 83, 109)',
                     name="A"
                     ))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=["B"],
                     y=[50],
                     marker_color='rgb(26, 118, 255)',
                     name="B"
                     ))
fig.update_layout(
    title='Test',
    xaxis_tickfont_size=14,
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Time (ms)',
        titlefont_size=16,
        tickfont_size=14,
    ),
    legend=dict(
        x=1.0,
        y=1.0,
        bgcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
        bordercolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    ),
    barmode='group',
    bargap=0.02,
    bargroupgap=0.6,
    width=500,
    height=400
)

#fig.show()

if not os.path.exists("images"):
    os.mkdir("images")

fig.write_image("images/fig1.pdf")
```

Comment: Quite a lot of that code isn't really relevant to the question - could you trim it down to just the bit that answers their question, then explain why it does? :)